# Hangs on first line

Tags: errors

I frequently get this with no way to go on:

> ```
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6730 64-bit)
> entering extended mode
> (C:/Users/Eckert/Documents/texzeta.txt
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.1 \documentclass
>                   {article}
> ?
> ```

I thought the `\documentclass{article}` was a mandatory first line?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you maybe run `pdftex` instead of `pdflatex` (or `tex` instead of `latex`; note the missing `la` in each case)?

Comment: Welcome, you are running in TeX-mode, not LaTeX. Look for `pdflatex` in your editor.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258617/35864 (and also to a lesser extent: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27144/35864 with a few explanations about TeX vs LaTeX).

Comment: I was actually using the default option "pdfLaTex+MakeIndex+BibTex":  I have to change that to "pdfLaTeX" (only) killing whatever those other things are in order to make it run.